# Retrieving values using Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a method to search by database based on categories, I am opting for using the SpringJPa derived queries. Check below

```
Page<TriviaQuestion> findByCategoryOrCategory(String categoryOne, String categoryTwo, Pageable pageable);
```

This is the method that is using the method. The result of the getTotalElements is O which is not supposed to be.

```
    public ResponseEntity<APIResponse> getQuizByTwoCategoryOnly(String categoryOne, String categoryTwo, int page, int size) {
        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page,size);
        Page<TriviaQuestion> response = questionRepository.findByCategoryOrCategory(categoryOne,categoryTwo,pageable);
        log.info("I retrieved {} entities",response.getTotalElements());
        Set<QuizResponse> quizResponses = new HashSet<>();
            for(TriviaQuestion question : response){
                QuizResponse quizResponse = new QuizResponse();
                quizResponse.setQuestion(question.getQuestion());
                quizResponse.setCategory(question.getCategory());
                quizResponse.setDifficulty(question.getDifficulty());
                quizResponse.setAnswer(question.getCorrectAnswer());
                Set<String> options = question.getIncorrectAnswer().stream().map(WrongAnswers::getWrongAnswers).collect(Collectors.toSet());
                options.add(question.getCorrectAnswer());
                quizResponse.setOptions(options);
                quizResponses.add(quizResponse);
            }
        log.info("I am suppose to pass {} ", quizResponses.size());
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new APIResponse(HttpStatus.FOUND,quizResponses,"Quiz questions based on to categories"));
    }
```

I have used native queries but still I have no result from my database

```
"SELECT * FROM TRIVIA_QUESTION" +
           " WHERE " +
           " CATEGORY =?1 OR CATEGORY =?2";
```

This is the query Hibernate genereted.

```
select tq1_0.id,tq1_0.category,tq1_0.correct_answer,tq1_0.difficulty,tq1_0.question from trivia_question tq1_0 where tq1_0.category=? or tq1_0.category=? limit ?,?
```

Now I have tried checking if these queries are correct by putting them in my database directly and they produced the required results.
This is the query I used in mysql, which is similar to what JPA genereted, I just put my own values.

```
select tq1_0.id,tq1_0.category,tq1_0.correct_answer,tq1_0.difficulty,tq1_0.question
from trivia_question tq1_0 where tq1_0.category= 'Science: Computers' or tq1_0.category= 'Politics' limit 0,15;
```

Comment: What are the values of your Pageable and are you using 0 or 1 based, Aksim are you setting the spring.data.web.pageable.one-indexed-parameters configuration property?

Comment: The values of my pageable are 0 for the page and 15 for the size…and yes I am using 0 not 1.  I used the same values  in checking for the result in the database itself and I got the expected result

Comment: I don't think `?1` are valid bind markers. It should be `?` or `:1`.

Can't explain why the derived query won't work though.

Answer (score 0):

put your parameters in a list and use this

```
Page<TriviaQuestion> findByCategoryIn(List<Category> categories, Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: i checked in spring website, i found you can use a list with 'in' https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/jpa/query-methods.html

Comment: Thank you, this worked but can you please explain why? 
Does JPA process having IN different from having to use WHERE with OR

Comment: you can use or by using jpql i updated my answer i am not sure but i think the problem when use or with same parameter it doesnt work

Comment: if this is helped you why you didnt accept the answer

Comment: Yes I think so, I tried the updated answer and it did not work, I don't think SpringJPA allows you to do something like findBy("x")Or("x")